# Creating a flat checkbox style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface

I'm trying to replicate the checkboxes seen in this image:

[css-custom-checkboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iof11.png)

I've been using the xaml from this example as a starting point:

[web.archive.org - WPF CheckBox style (inspired by android)](https://web.archive.org/web/20160303041055/http://www.wpfhelper.com:80/index.php/android-ui-for-wpf/23-modern-ui-for-wpf/android-ui-for-wpf/26-wpf-checkbox-style-inspired-by-android)

**My requirements:**

- Solid background.
- No border.
- Checkmark area and checkmark resizes with control.
- Checkmark is centered in the checkbox area.

**My Code:**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:DMStyle2CheckBox}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="32" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="138" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{DynamicResource MyFocusVisualStyte}" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                <BulletDecorator>
                    <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                        <Grid Background="{x:Null}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Height, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                              MinHeight="30" MinWidth="30" ShowGridLines="False">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="4*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="6*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="4*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <!-- Checkmark Box -->
                            <Border Name="InnerBorder" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="5" BorderThickness="1" 
                                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>

                            <!-- Checkmark -->
                            <Path x:Name="CheckMark" Data="F1 M 9.97498,1.22334L 4.6983,9.09834L 4.52164,9.09834L 0,5.19331L 1.27664,3.52165L 4.255,6.08833L 8.33331,
                                  1.52588e-005L 9.97498,1.22334 Z" Fill="{Binding CheckMarkColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" Opacity="0" 
                                  Stretch="Uniform" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="3" />

                            <Path Name="InderminateMark"  Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="4" Data="M0,4 L1,5 5,1 4,0" Opacity="0" 
                                  Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="0" Fill="#808080" />
                        </Grid>
                    </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark" Duration="0:0:0.2" To="1" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked" >
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark" Duration="0:0:0.2" To="0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="InderminateMark" Duration="0:0:0.2" To="1" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ContentPresenter Margin="4,0,4,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                </BulletDecorator>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="InnerBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{Binding BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="CheckMark" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource Color.Black}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="CheckMark" Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource Color.Black}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="InderminateMark" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource Color.Black}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="InnerBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Color.Black}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

For the most part this code does what I want. The checkmark is the biggest issues for me. It's not centered or resizable and it overflows the checkmark area.

I've tried playing with the grid columns and rows that hold the checkmark but its becoming increasingly frustrating. Ideally I would like to get rid of the grid columns and rows but haven't had much luck with that either.

I've looked at every SO question about wpf checkbox styles I could find and have searched for any other online resources but most of them don't come close to what I want. I even attempted to modify the default template with Expression Blend but that didn't work out either.

Comment: Does putting the path element into it's own grid help to allow WPF to center it?

Comment: @JohnPeters Wrapping the path in a basic grid with no attributes caused the checkmark to be positioned way outside the checkbox. If I apply the grid column/row attributes to the grid I get the same result I have currently.

Comment: Grids allow you to overlay things, I suspect the path behavior you see is that exactly what the path tells it to do.  You have the shape but the offsets are not playing nice with WPF layout system or are simply wrong.  Can you see if an image of the same size works?

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/78e0befe21f8fd771aa09a95f77e0364259ed9f8/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.CheckBox.xaml

Comment: @JohnPeters If I use an image it appears to work though its very slightly off center. I'm taking a look at the link you provided. We'll see if I can gather anything from it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out based on this template I found: [Circle-checkbox-style-in-WPF](http://findnerd.com/list/view/Circle-checkbox-style-in-WPF/22637/)

**Style Template**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:FlatCheckBox}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="32" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="138" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{DynamicResource MyFocusVisualStyte}" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                <Grid Background="Transparent">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="24" />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Border Background="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                            BorderBrush="{Binding BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                            BorderThickness="{Binding BorderThickness, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                            CornerRadius="0" Width="20" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <Grid>
                            <Path x:Name="CheckMark" Data="F1 M 9.97498,1.22334L 4.6983,9.09834L 4.52164,9.09834L 0,5.19331L 1.27664,3.52165L 4.255,
                                6.08833L 8.33331,1.52588e-005L 9.97498,1.22334 Z" Fill="{Binding CheckMarkColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" 
                                Margin="3" Opacity="0" Stretch="Fill" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" x:Name="content" Margin="5,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="CheckMark" Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Class for custom dependency properties**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace Control_Styles.Styles
{
    public partial class FlatCheckBox : CheckBox
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CheckMarkColorProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("CheckMarkColor", typeof(Brush), typeof(FlatCheckBox));

        public Brush CheckMarkColor
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(CheckMarkColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CheckMarkColorProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can set a style

```
<Style TargetType="CheckBox" x:Key="Flat_CheckBox">            
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>            
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="60"/>
    <Setter Property="UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>            
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />       

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">                    
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightSkyBlue" />
        </Trigger>                
    </Style.Triggers>

</Style>
```

Comment: Am I missing something with this code? This looks like a generic style for overriding the checkbox. Unfortunately that won't work for my needs. It was the first thing I tried. 

The checkbox "box" and checkmark don't resize with the control. I need both to grow and shrink to stay vertically aligned with the content presenter (the text).